# Unable to understand a line in Google CodePreview's README

Tags: macos, google-code, google-app-engine

The README is in Google's [codepreview](http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/) which uses [Google-appengine](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/).

> To run the app locally (e.g. for
>   testing), download the Google App
>        Engine SDK from http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html.
>   You
>        can then run the server using
>
> ```
>   make serve
> ```

I run `make serve` in my terminal after moving Google-appengine.app to my Application -folder in OS X Leopard.

I get

```
make: *** No rule to make target `serve'.  Stop.
```

**How can you run the `make serve` to run the server for Google AppEngine?**

Comment: Please, create tag for Google-appengine.

Comment: Tag created....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run a make target you have to be in the same directory as the Makefile, as far as I know. So after you download and extract/mount (*I don't know which SDK you downloaded: Python or Java*), `cd` into the directory with the `Makefile` and *then* you can type `make server`. Then it should work.

Comment: I downloaded App-Engine Launcher for Mac. I assumed that some SDK is inside it.

Comment: Did you go into codepreview's directory which contains the Makefile? That's where you type make serve

Answer (score 1):

I think that may be a menu item within `Google-appengine.app`. Try running it and poking around in the menus.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I did not find such a menu-item, not even by searching its manuals with the keywords.